# How can I resolve a circular reference issue in my GraphQL schema for modeling a player and matches?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql

we have a schema that models a player with all their game stats and a match between players.  At the moment we have a circular reference because a player has matches and matches have players.

Initial issue: When the app launches we download the user's stats which includes matches and the players in those matches.  Because of the circular reference the query depth is set to 3 so it will retrieve the user, then matches, then players in matches.  The issue is that it doesn't retrieve the players in the match.  If I change the call to instead of returning a player but return JSON, the JSON contains all the data including the players, but it's not clear how to put that JOSN into a player with all the nested data.  So what we need is a dev with strong enough experience with Amplfy's implementation of GraphQL so we can modify the schema or the custom GraphQLRequests to get the data we need.

We've been working with Amplify's V1 SDK for Swift, and need to move to V2.  I don't necessarily need help with the Swift, but I'm not opposed to working with someone on it.
Need to implement social auth
Need auth rules for data models
Need to get players paginated and ordered by high scores for leaderboard
Need to subscribe to matches

Comment: This is not a circular reference, this is just a very common many-to-many relationship. Try with a depth of 4 or preferably something bigger like 7.